# Reactjs: How to render an image from a bitmap?

Tags: reactjs

I've tried so far:

```js
<img style={{ width: 66, height: 58 }}
     source={{ uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' }} />
```

Result:

> is not assignable to type DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLImageElement>`.

```js
<Image style={{ width: 66, height: 58 }}
       source={{ uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' }}/>
```

Result:

> 'Image' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef`

Comment: Did you try setting it as `background-image`? I.e. `style={{backgroundImage: 'data:image/png;base64...'}}`

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing it right, but 
<background-image source={{ uri:'data:image/png;base64,{this.bitmap}' }} />
gave me: 
Property 'background-image' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Comment: See my answer for clarification

Comment: is this React or React-Native?

Comment: shouldn't you just use the src? `<img src="data:image/png;..." />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I was saying in the comments, for HTML you are supposed to use the `src` tag on an image element.

```
<img style={{ width: 66, height: 58 }} src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

[**See it live**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-30fif)

Comment: @kryp yep! happy to help :) let me know if you have more questions / need help with other stuff! :)

Answer (score 1):

In HTML a base64 encoded image is displayed this way:

```
<img style="width:66px;height:58px;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

This should work in React

```
<img style={{ width: 66, height: 58 }} src={"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to the `background-image` CSS property:

```
<div style={{ width: 66, height: 58, backgroundImage: "url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==')" }}/>
```